# How to convert fetch to axios in raectjs?

Tags: reactjs, axios

As i just know basic of axios and not able to convert this fetch to axios method. I have the following piece of code which is working perfect i am confused do i need to use Json.stringify or any other json method as what i have read is axios do automatically converts to json
here is my code

```
const handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setData({
      ...data,
      isSubmitting: true,
      errorMessage: null
    });
    fetch("https://hookedbe.herokuapp.com/api/login", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: data.email,
        password: data.password
      })
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        }
        throw res;
      })
      .then(resJson => {
        dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN",
            payload: resJson
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setData({
          ...data,
          isSubmitting: false,
          errorMessage: error.message || error.statusText
        });
      });
  };
```

changing it to axios

```
const url = "https://hookedbe.herokuapp.com/api/login"
const body = {
    username: data.email,
    password: data.password
};
axios.post(url, body)
  .then(res => {
      dispatch({
          type: "LOGIN",
          payload: res.data
      })
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://github.com/axios/axios)?

Comment: @Parth what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axios.post`, much easier syntax and no need for any json conversion:

```
const payload = {
    username: data.email,
    password: data.password
};
axios.post("https://hookedbe.herokuapp.com/api/login", payload)
  .then(res => {
      dispatch({
          type: "LOGIN",
          payload: res.data
      })
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: Hi @HermitCrab  ```.then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN",
            payload: res
        })
      })``` or should i send   ```.then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN",
            payload: res.data
        })
      })```

Comment: You should do `payload: res.data`. I edited my answer with this

Comment: Hi @HermitCrab i just edited my code will it work? i used body and url and passing it inside post method  ```payload: res.data```